# Repeat function itself without setInterval based on its finish

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, setinterval

I need my program to repeat itself continuously. My program starts to fetch proxies from servers and saves them to a database and then send those saved proxies to another server again. So I don't know how long it takes for my program to do this task.

I wanna know what happens if any problem happens that makes this startJob() function take more than 30 seconds.

Does setInterval call it again or waits for function to finish?
What's the best approach for my program to repeat itself after it's done without setInterval?
(for exmaple startJob() being called again after it's done.)

I was wondering if it is ok to put this function in a loop with a big number like:

```
for ( let i = 0 ; i < 999999999 ; i ++ ) {
    await startJob()
}
```

Here is my code:

```
const startJob = async () => {
  await postProxyToChannel()
  grabProxies()
}

setInterval(function(){
  startJob()
}, (30000))
```

grabProxies() takes about 10 seconds and postProxyToChannel() takes about 5 seconds on my server.

Comment: No, it is not a good approach to either include an infinite loop, nor depend on a 30 seconds delay. Things can mess up unexpectedly, not to mention wasting resources. You can use either callbacks or promises, and call your function again in the onSuccess, and deal with errors in the onFailure.

Comment: If you put it in a loop, then *no other JS would run*. Unless you have web workers or something, but most of the time your code would run in a single thread. A better question is to focus on what you're actually trying to achieve, because it currently looks like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter what happens inside `startJob`, `setInterval` will call it every 30 seconds. This means that `postProxyToChannel` will be called every 30 seconds. If *that* function throws, you'll get an unhandled Promise rejection, but the interval will continue.

Even if `postProxyToChannel` takes, say, 45 seconds, that won't prevent `startJob` from being called again before the prior `startJob` has completed.

If you want to make sure that `startJob` is only called 30 seconds after it finishes, you could `await` it in your `for` loop, then `await` a Promise that resolves every 30 seconds:

```
(async () => {
  for ( let i = 0 ; i < 999999999 ; i ++ ) {
    await startJob();
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 30000));
  }
})()
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('There was an error', err);
  });
```

But it would probably make more sense just to have a recursive call of `startJob`, eg:

```
const startJob = async () => {
  try {
    await postProxyToChannel();
  } catch(e) {
    // handle error
  }
  grabProxies();
  setTimeout(startJob, 30000);
};
startJob();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yup an infinite loop sounds good, that can be compared with a timer to pause the loop:

```
   const timer = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

  (async function() {
     while(true) {
        await postProxyToChannel();
        await grabProxies();
        await timer(30000);
     }
  })();
```

Now that loop will run the task, wait 30secs, then do that again. Therefore the loop will not run every 30secs but will usually take longer. To adjust that, you could measure the time the task took, then await the rest of the time:

```
  const start = Date.now();

  await postProxyToChannel();
  await grabProxies();

  await timer(30000 - (Date.now() - start));
```

Comment: I like this approach, but maybe
```
     while(true) {
        const waiting = timer(30000);
        await postProxyToChannel();
        await grabProxies();
        await waiting;
     }
```
So no calculation of Date.now